# How to check inside the Worker thread if the Main UI Thread is sleeping or not active

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have created a Visual Studio 2019 app, with OutputPanes, one is used for viewing Traces Logs from the WorkerThread.

In the WorkerThread, I fill a `CStringList mStrDebugList` if somewhat useful has happened, and inform the Main UI with `PostMessage` to read & show now.

```cpp
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  TRACE Debug messsages for this App wide 
void TRACE_DEBUG(LPCTSTR pszstring)
{
    TRACE(pszstring);

    CTestApp* pApp = (CTestApp*)AfxGetApp();
    if (pApp)
    {
        TAutoLock lock(res);
        theApp.mStrDebugList.AddTail(pszstring);
    }
```

This works, but if the App is minimized or not in the foreground, after hours the `CStringList` contains too many elements (> 20k) and the Main UI is unresponsive (~5Min) until all elements are read & removed in the UI.

```cpp
void COutputWnd::FillInfoWindow()
{
    TestApp* pApp = (CTestApp*)AfxGetApp();
    if (pApp)
    {
        TAutoLock lock(res);

        CString str;
        while (!theApp.mStrDebugList.IsEmpty ())
        {
            str.Format(_T("%5d %s"),nCounter, theApp.mStrDebugList.GetHead ());     
            m_wndOutputDebug.AddString (str);
            theApp.mStrDebugList.RemoveHead ();
        }

        // Scroll to the end of Listbox
        int nCount = m_wndOutputDebug.GetCount();
        m_wndOutputDebug.SetTopIndex(nCount-1);
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I check inside the WorkerThread if the UI is not active (dormant), to prevent filling the `CStringList` with too many elements?

Comment: You mentioned the word "sleep".  Are you actually calling `sleep()` from the UI thread?  The actual UI thread should remain responsive to messages and should not be put to sleep.  EDIT TAutoLock should be OK, if this is what you meant by "sleep", as long as you don't lock the resource except for single log entries.

Comment: Message loops and UIs don't stop working just because the window is hidden/minimized. You say you are using `PostMessage()`, but there is no such call in the code you have shown. The real problem is that whatever you are using to trigger `FillInfoWindow()` is not working properly. Fix that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the state UI don't stop working, if the window is hidden/minimized. That is true, I wasn't sure anymore. I have myself deferred posting the real message to Update the OutputWnd in OnPaint `AfxGetMainWnd()->SendMessageToDescendants(WM_COMMAND, AFX_IDS_IDLEMESSAGE); // update Output Wnd `. That would explain this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is wrong. What will you be doing if the UI (main) thread is "dormant"? Prevent the worker thread from working, ie suspend it? Will it no longer be collecting data? And what will happen when the UI is brought to the foreground again? The worker thread will have to collect ALL the data, which will still need to be added to the debug window, all at once, so the total response time will be yet longer.

If it's adding the data to the debug window (I guess a listbox-derived class) that takes so long, there is no real solution, they need to be added anyway. Only some optimizations:

- Call `m_wndOutputDebug.SetRedraw(FALSE);` before adding the strings and `m_wndOutputDebug.SetRedraw(TRUE);` and `m_wndOutputDebug.Invalidate();` when you are done, maybe the delay is caused by the UI attempting to draw the debug window immediately after each item is added.
- Avoid those `GetHead()/RemoveHead()` calls for browsing the list (it's overhead, as it may rearrange/realloc the list), instead call `RemoveAll()` when you are done, there is no problem with this because you lock the operation.

A side note (not performance-related), why do you need to call `AfxGetApp()`? You are not doing anything with it (`pApp`) anyway. And you have the `theApp` singleton available (`AfxGetApp()` should just return the address of `theApp`, no?).

Comment: Yes, I was also trying to solve flickering issues in the OutputWindow the very wrong way, by slowing down the WorkerThread. Thanks for the optimizations tips. Especially I wasn't aware that AfxGetApp ist consuming many CPU cycles. I have measured that on my machine ~300us vs ~40us.